# How smart phones can be viewed as storage devices by the OS?

Tags: storage, smartphone

I wanted to view the partition tables of my android and ipod using gparted.But, I could not since the OS does not recognize smart phones as storage devices.So,why is this behaviour and how can I force the OS to recognize smart phones as storage devices??

Comment: Its because of how their USB capabilities are designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plug USB cable, most of them work as real USB drive by default.
Otherwise, check your phone/tablet/player settings and try to find an option like "use as USB storage" and turn it on.

If you have no such option in your device at all, then you must find and install drivers (if  they exist).
And if drivers are designed to bring you USB drive interface then it will be OK.

But they can provide another interface via USB and use drivers, so that they "pretend" like normal drives but aren't in real. And in this case you can't force OS to recognize your device as storage device.